# Repeat cell content in excel to fit its width or height

Tags: excel

I have columns with merged cells, that the content dispears in other pages of the document, I want some how to repeat the content to make sure that it apears in every page, so to make this clear consider the followkng sinario:

For a cell that contains a letter C for exemple, how to make excel generates other Cs with some spaces between them in the cell to fill the new width?

There could be a text in the cell to be repeated.

Is there any function to do that?

Edit:

I tried with `print titles`, but since the column contents changes, it does not work.

Comment: No, there is no formula that can automatically do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this result using a custom cell format. For example:-

1. Set a *Custom* number format of `*C@` for the cell.
2. Enter a single C in the cell.
3. The cell will fill with Cs.

The asterisk tells Excel to repeat the character that's following. In this case the character that follows is a "C". The final @ specifies that the cell should contain text. You can replace this with a 0 (zero) or a more complicated format (like in number formatting).

What happens, then, is that the "C" you entered will be preceded by the number of fill characters the cell can take. If you enter "John" the display will be CCCCCCCCCCJohn. The Formnat `*=0.00` would show the number 55.1234 as ==========55.12

The sequence can be reversed with a format like `@ *+` which would produce a output like "John +++++++++++".
Unfortunately, I don't know of a way to repeat more than one character, even if the second character is a space. For this kind of thing Excel has the RPT() function. `=RPT("C ",5)` will repeat a C, followed by a space, 5 times. Unfortunately, the RPT function doesn't seem to accept Char(10) (Alt + carriage return), limiting its use to fill cells vertically. Also, one would have to adjust a cell to the width of the function's output instead of the output being adjusted to fit the cell width.

Comment: Thank you for this contribution, despite that I would prefer a pattern that allows `content space/separator content space/separator..`, this is the closest functionality.